# onclick is still giving me problems

Tags: php, javascript

Been looking at this for a while and even posted another question and got half the answer but the error still persists 
expected ';' character 392

Comment: Please do not post PHP source code. It is meaningless in the context. Please always post the full, generated code as seen in the browser. (Downvote not mine, though)

Comment: I'd edit out your LivePerson Account info, wouldn't want mine or any of my clients account info public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, follow Pekka's advice!

But, you error lies in that you're missing a `';` to end one of your strings.

In your code, you have:

```
escape(document.location) +' imageUrl={URL} lpButtonCTTUrl = ...
```

But, I think you want to close that string and start a new statement.  You'd have to add `';` to the end of that `imageUrl` string like this:

```
escape(document.location) +' imageUrl={URL}'; lpButtonCTTUrl = ...
```

Answer (score 12):

It is extremely bad style to put that much code into an inline `onclick` event exactly for this reason: It becomes a *bitch* to debug. I would recommend creating a function - named "lpButtonClick" or something - in a separate .js file, or a `<script>` block in the document's head.

I'm sure that when you do that, and separate each command into one line, the reason for that `;` error will come to light quickly.

Your link's onclick event would then look like this:

```
onClick="return lpButtonClick();"
```

alternatively, iyou could avoid setting the event in the markup altogether. If you work with jQuery,  giving the link an ID would look like this - put it into the `ready` event:

```
$("#linkID").click(function() { return lpButtonClick(); });
```

Comment: I would also add, to even further simplify things, you could make your HREF and SRC values php variables. This would make debugging HTML/JS problems even easier by making your code more readable.